# Add image between Content ( string ) in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a blog site that I want admins to be able to add articles to, such that when admins are adding text, they can upload images between paragraphs and have them displayed in the same way, but I have no idea how to implement this part of my program.

```
public class Author : EntityBase
{
    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class AuthorDto
{
    public IFormFile ProfileImage { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

In service (application section) :

```
var url = _fileUploader.Upload(request.ProfileImage , $"Author:{request.Username}");

public string Upload(IFormFile file, string path)
{
    var pathDirectory = $"{_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}//UploadedFiles//AuthorPictures//{path}";
    if (!Directory.Exists(pathDirectory))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathDirectory);

    var filename = ToFileName(DateTime.Now) + "-" + file.FileName;
    var filePath = $"{pathDirectory}{filename}";

    using var output = File.Create(filePath);
    file.CopyTo(output);

    return $"{path}//{filename}";
}

private static string ToFileName(DateTime date)
{
    return $"{date.Year:0000}-{date.Month:00}-{date.Day:00}-{date.Hour:00}-{date.Minute:00}-{date.Second:00}";
}
```

Actually I have problem in `Html_RazorPage` definition and my model.

Comment: This question seems very broad.  What are the hiccups here?  What I usually do is create an endpoint (controller) that serves an image based in it's ID.  (return the File)  You can then set the <img src to that endpoint.  (ex: '<img src="/serve_jpg?id={uid}"> )  This ensures that the user is authorized to retrieve that resource and prevents "deep links".  You can also choose a different filename if it is to become a download.

Comment: `"I have problem in Html_RazorPage definition and my model"`, could you please share more details about what issue you are facing in `Html_RazorPage` so that it can be much easier to assist. In addition, if you could share relevant code snippet that would be great.

Comment: @pcalkins
 In fact, I'm struggling with the model and the implementation of views. I don't know how to upload an image inside the text that the user is entering and avoid the database from becoming too large. Also, I'm not sure how to display them in order.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron 
 In fact, I'm struggling with the model and the implementation of views. I don't know how to upload an image inside the text that the user is entering and avoid the database from becoming too large. Also, I'm not sure how to display them in order.

Comment: You can just store the file path in the DB... or even just the name if the path is always the same.  As for the model the file bit of the view model would be IFile something like:  public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }  For the WYSIWYG part, that could get complicated.  I would start a new post breaking down the various questions into single posts and including code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have some placeholders (predefined text constants) to insert images.

For example, you could have this one for the profile image: `@profileImage`.

After that, you will be able to insert the appropriate content for this placeholder in the right place, adding the necessary logic to your views at the backend, replacing the `@profileImage` placeholder with the URL of the image in the HTML markup.

Also, you will be able to build some page previews in real time, handling these placeholders using JS. Of course, for this purpose, you will need an API endpoint to get the image.

Besides, I recommend taking a look at [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/index.html) or any other library that provides [WYSIWYG](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) functionality. For example, there is the [image component](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/image.html) in the CKEditor which allows to insert, upload, resize, style, caption, and link images.